# laravel 8 install Imagick for PHP and Apache on Windows 10

Tags: php, xampp, laravel-8, qr-code, imagick

I have done all steps properly to install imagick on my PC, yet am getting error: "**You need to install the imagick extension to use this back end**", while trying to convert QRcode into PNG format. Am using Xampp for Apache.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
        <!-- generate function from simple-qr code package -->
        <!-- {{!! QrCode::size(250)->generate($row->link); !!}} -->
        <img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(100)->generate($row->link)) !!} "> 
    </div>
    <div class="codesource-link" style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="https://https://codesource.io/">Download</a>
    </div>
```

This image proves it:

[image]

Am not sure there might be some hidden steps am missing here maybe, it would be great if you offer me your help.

Comment: "_I have done all steps properly to install imagick on my PC_" How? Did you enable the extension? In the _correct_ `php.ini` file? Does it show up on a `<?php phpinfo() ?>` page? Did you restart the webserver?

Comment: Yes I did. You can check it out now. I have already edited the question.

Comment: Are you using a library/package for qrcode generation? Might want to check how it determines if imagick is installed/where this error message is coming from

Comment: am using the qrcode direct without adding providers dependencies or controllers. I just installed the qrcode using composer and used it straight in the HTML. It worked fine except for the image.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved it. I added `apache\bin` in `PATH` and rebooted the computer. Everything worked fine since.